# MSDeploy - Transform configuration twice in the same deploy

Tags: xml, web-config, msdeploy, web.config-transform

In my `web.config` file i have two sections that can  tranforem at deploy.

1. Environment settings (include connection string...)
2. Authentication (include  use Auth or not)

Both sections are independent.
So what i want for example is to transform first by the environment (integration\production) and afterwards to transform it again  by authentication (add\ remove)

I have tried to make alot of copies of the configurations i want (`Web.WithAuth.Integration.Config`, `Web.WithOutAuth.Integration.Config` and same for production) but i think there is a better solution. 
How can i achive this with msdeploy??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add to my msdeploy command `deployProfile` parameter (that contains the auth replacement\add) and a `configuration` parameter (include the environment changes).

this two parameters make the `.config` file to pass two transformations.